# Base32 implementation in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, base32

Does anyone have base32 implementation in Delphi?

I found: http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/21566 but it is not exactly base32 
(Base32 is a base-32 transfer encoding using the twenty-six letters A-Z and six digits 2-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked at [Torry's](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=210)? There is [SZCodeBaseX.zip v.1.3.3](http://www.torry.net/vcl/internet/coding/SZCodeBaseX.zip), which is said to have Base32 and Base64 encoding. It claims to be RFC 3548 compatible; although I have **not** tried it.

Comment: @Sorrow yes, but in Delphi 2010 it's just 䅖求䡁䅍䅤杁䕁䅕杢橂䝁䄸䈀兘㵁㴽䘶〰 on the encode output

Comment: @JustMe now I am just guessing (I stopped at D2005 ;), but it seems like a unicode string; can you either get byte-by-byte sequence of it, or use non-unicode type to see what happens? I might be wrong, though, but please, post the results.

Comment: @Sorrow Looking at the source I found it's not the Unicode problem - function operates on pbyte pointers and assumes that SizeOf(char) = SizeOf(byte). I don't really know how to fix it thought :/

Comment: try making all the String stataments AnsiString

Comment: @opc0de and all `char` -> `ansichar`